# How to get Network object for connected Wifi network?

Tags: android

We can get information about the current Wifi network like this:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo connectionInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
```

However i see no obvious way to obtain the [`Network`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Network) object related to this `WifiInfo`.

We can also iterate over all `Network`s:

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

for (Network network : connectivityManager.getAllNetworks()) {
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(network);
    String extraInfo = networkInfo.getExtraInfo();

    if (extraInfo.equals(connectionInfo.getSSID())) {
        return network;
    }
}
```

But since Android 9.0, the `extraInfo` is blank, even if i have location permission.

Is there a safe way to obtain the current `Network` related to the connected wifi network?

Comment: Location permission is only half of the story. The location services (in settings menu) on the phone must also be enabled

Comment: Try this `if (connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network).hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) return network;` By this you will know that this `network` represents a wifi network. Haven't tested this yet, but read this in docs.

Comment: Also, have you tried this `if (networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) return network;`? Of-course you won't know the ssid of network, but you will atleast know that `network` object represents a wifi network.